# PHP dynamic namespaces

Tags: php, dynamic, namespaces

I need to be able to do this:

```
$ns = "\\common\\components\\cfoBi\\i18n\\{$countryCode}\\gimmea";
use $USP;
```

Obviously this won't work. So how can I do this? Have "dynamic namespaces"?

Comment: You can't have dynamic namepaces: why not create a language factory instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible. Namespaces, imports and aliases are resolved at compile time.

However, it is possible to create objects from a class name that is built at runtime:

```
$className = "common\\components\\cfoBi\\i18n\\{$countryCode}\\gimmea";

$object = new $className();
```

See PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Comment: Yep, I am familiar with that solution: of creating classes from dynamic class names. However, the best solution for me would have been the dynamic namespaces.