# Please how can i dynamically set a namespace for any class controller in multiple folders in php MVC Framework

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, namespaces, composer-php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Core;
use Application\Core\View;


class Router {


    public function __construct() {}
    /**
     method that routes the url
     * @param  [array] $url [contains an array of current url in the browser]
     * @return [object]      [an instance ocontroller being called]
     */
    
    public static function route($url) {
        $controller = (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] !== "") ? ucwords($url[0])."Controller" : "HomeController";
        $controller = "Framework\Controllers\\".$controller;
        array_shift($url);
        $method = (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] !== "") ? $url[0] : "index";
        array_shift($url);
        $arguments = empty($url) ? [] : array_values($url);
        if (self::isValidController($controller) === true) {
            $controller = new $controller;
            if(self::isValidMethod($controller, $method) === true) {
                empty($arguments) ? $controller->{$method}() : call_user_func_array([$controller, $method], $arguments);
            } else {
                http_response_code(404);
                exit(View::render("http", "codes/404", ["title" => "Page Not Found"]));
            }
        }else {
            http_response_code(404);
            exit(View::render("http", "codes/404", ["title" => "Page Not Found"]));
        } 
    }

    private static function isValidController($controller){
        if(!empty($controller)){
            return (preg_match('/\A[a-z]+\z/i', $controller) || class_exists($controller) || strtolower($controller) === "homecontroller") ? true : false;
        }else { 
            return false; 
        }
    }

    private static function isValidMethod($controller, $method){
        if(!empty($method)){
            return (preg_match('/\A[a-z]+\z/i', $method) || method_exists($controller, $method)  || strtolower($method) === "index") ? true : false;
        }else { 
            return false; 
        }
    }

    public static function redirect($location) {
        if (!headers_sent()) {
            header('Location: '.DOMAIN.$location);
        }else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href="'.DOMAIN.$location.'";';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<noscript>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$location.'" />';
            echo '</noscript>';
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

** This is my router class by which controllers are namespaced to just Framework\Controllers. But i want to dynamically load inside folders in Controller folder like e.g., 'Backend' - namespaced as Framework\Controllers\Backend and be able to do this by dynamically loading any valid class controller found in any of the folders inside Framework\Controllers. I'm using PSR-4 autolading with composer. **
*Please any answer would be appreciated*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP dynamic namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418958/php-dynamic-namespaces)

Comment: Is there anything **not** working with the given code? Then please explain what issue you are facing

Comment: Symfony's [Finder Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) seems to be a solution. You'd apply something like this (recursively by default): `$finder->files()->in("<path-to-controllers-folder>")->name("<name-of-controller-file>");`. Maybe you should take [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) into consideration too.

Comment: The Symfony's Finder Component fits my solution. Thank you alot.

Comment: Well there're no issues with the code. It works fine. i just needed to add more directories in the Framework\Controllers for better organization.

Answer (score -1):

Symfony's [Finder Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) seems to be a solution. You'd apply something like this (recursively by default):

```
$finder->files()->in('<path-to-controllers-folder>')->name('<name-of-controller-file>');
```

---

I already wrote the above in my comment, but I thought to write an answer instead, in order to just give you some suggestions:

Note that there is no *"PHP MVC framework"*. Instead you can say *"a (PHP) framework for (PHP) MVC application(s)"*. Why? Because a ***framework*** is not an ***MVC application***.

**The framework:**

A *framework* is just a bundle of libraries brought together under the same roof, waiting to be used by one or multiple MVC applications. Here's a list of library types - with links pointing to some personally preferred example resources - which should/could be part of a framework:

- a [router](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute);
- a route dispatcher (most probably including a [route invoker](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Invoker));
- an error handling library (read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) article);
- a [library](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-diactoros/) for creating and handling all HTTP messages, e.g. the request and the response;
- a library to find and load configuration files - which could use something like the already recommended [component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html);
- a library for loading and rendering template files;
- other libraries.

**The MVC application:**

On the other hand, completely separated from the framework, you have the *MVC application*. It's the actual program which processes each user request and is structured in the three components (*C*, *V* & *M*), after the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle. So, the MVC app structure ensures the separation of the *presentation logic* (the *V* & *C*) from the *business logic* (the *M*). What should contain an MVC app?

- classes/interfaces to represent each MVC component, e.g. the *M*, the *V*, the *C*;
- a [dependency injection container](https://php-di.org/) to create, prepare and inject the dependencies into the class instances of the three MVC components;
- a [front controller](https://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/) to match each HTTP request against a predefined routes list and dispatch the found route;
- configuration files - containing the routes list(s), along with the definition values and the parameters for the DI container;
- client-side assets (template files, js & css files, images, fonts, etc);
- libraries to handle the client-side assets ([jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), etc).
- other classes/libraries.

It is really great that you're trying to implement your own framework components (like a router). That way you'd definitely learn a lot. Though, implementing framework libraries by yourself would take a very long time. So, instead, I'd suggest you to use the (open source) libraries developed by other people/companies and to just concentrate yourself on how to embed and extend them in such a way, that they properly fit into your vision about future MVC application(s). By doing this, you'll still have the chance to learn everything in regard of MVC, you'll achieve a solid, correctly implemented framework and, in the end, you'll be able to focus your energy on developing MVC apps.

Note that some/many frameworks include base classes for the MVC application components (M, V, & C) into their *framework* codebase. They do this just to help the users with helper methods residing in these classes. Though, these methods either aren't really needed, or they should be defined in base classes as part of the *MVC app(s)* instead. I speak about something like `BaseController`, `BaseView`, etc.

That said, here are some observations regarding your code:

- I suggest you to avoid using *static methods* and *singletons* (if you're already using them) entirely. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-9FjaOIsw8) meetup, for example, until the end. Afterwards you can decide for yourself.
- The router should only have one task to perform: to find a certain route in a predefined list of routes, based on the *HTTP method* (GET, POST, etc) and the *URI path* of the current request. It can then return the matched route as is (e.g. as object), or it may just return an array with the components of it (controller, method, arguments list). So, dispatching/invoking the found route (components) - by calling `call_user_func_array(['<controller-name>', '<method>'], [<arguments-list>])` - is the responsibility of another component (of a route dispatcher/invoker, for example, or even of the front controller itself).
- Having in mind that a framework code should be completely separated from the code of an MVC app, you shouldn't have `Framework\Controllers`. Instead, you could have `Framework\Router` and `App\Controllers`.
- You should avoid printing HTML code from PHP code as much as possible.